# Address each Matlab array element, one by one, independent from dimension (row vs. column)

Tags: arrays, matlab

I would like to do something with each element in an array. For a row array, I can do this:

```
array = [1 2 3];
i = 0;
for a = array
    i = i + 1;
end
fprintf('Number of iterations: %g\n', i)

Number of iterations: 3
```

It will output 3, so it actually accessed each array element one after another.

However if the array is a column, the same code will output just 1:

```
array = [1; 2; 3];
...

Number of iterations: 1
```

I wonder why exactly this happens and if there is a way to iterate through an array, independent from its "directional dimension" and without using `for i = 1:numel(array), a = array(i)`.

Comment: if you're dealing only with row- or column-vectors you could use `for a = array(:).'` to make sure you work on a row vector, since Matlab iterates over columns.

Comment: Consult chappjc's answer in the duplicate I have marked... specifically towards the end.  There are some intricacies you need to keep in mind when looping if you are using matrices as access indices into them.  @Benoit_11 however did mention a `tl;dr` comment summarizing the duplicate.

Comment: ahh @rayryeng I knew there was a duplicate somewhere! thanks haha

Comment: @Benoit_11 :D only because I knew what to look for.  I read that question/answer in the past and it's in my favourites.

Comment: @Benoit_11, why do you have a dot in your comment after `array(:)`? Is there any difference if I use simply `array(:)'`?

Comment: @texnic that's a habit of mine, using the [nonconjugate transpose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) instead of the conjugate transpose. When working with imaginary numbers it can be handy but when using real-only numbers there is no difference.

Comment: @texnic When dealing with real numbers, `'` and `.'` make no difference.  However if you have complex valued arrays, doing `.'` is what is known as the non-conjugate transpose.  Doing `'` on complex valued arrays not only transposes but also **negates** the imaginary component.  Doing `.'` maintains the sign of the imaginary component when transposing.  This small oversight has bit me in the @$$ in the past because I was unaware of this behaviour so I now just use `.'` due to force of habit.

Comment: @rayryeng, BTW, I wonder if marking this question a duplicate is correct. It sure relates to the other one, but the question itself is completely different. There is a very little chance that a person would find the other question looking for what I asked. Besides, even having found that question, you need to read it in detail to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a for loop is initialized with an array, it iterates column by column.  This may not be what you want, but that the built in behavior (see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html).

You can force your matrix into a linear row vector, so MATLAB will iterate the elements 1 by 1 with the following:

```
for i = A(:)'
    i % use each value of A
end
```

Normally, a combination of vector operations will be faster than a for loop, so only use a for loop when you can't think of the appropriate vector operation equivalent.